# Detect hover over ListBoxItem in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have a `ListBox` with a custom item template, and I want when the mouse hovers over an item in the `ListBox`, to set a property on the `DataContext` (the item the `ListBoxItem` is bound to).

I can quite easily change something visual, such as the background color of when I hover over using a `DataTrigger`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Name="Border">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="2,0,2,0"/>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                     Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I can't work out how to make the `DataTrigger` set a property on my `DataContext`, so my ViewModel can react to the hover over.

Unfortunately on this project I cannot make use of the Blend interactivity DLL which is often recommended for tasks like this as I am unable to introduce a new dependency in our install process.

Comment: What type of property you need to set??

Comment: Have you tried to add context as resource and bind the `Value` of the `DataContext` property to that resource in `DataTrigger`?

Comment: @petchirajan I just want my viewmodel to be notified. I've just got a rather cumbersome technique using two attached behaviours and two ICommands working.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - I got syntax errors with pretty much everything I tried in that regard.

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately, this cumbersome technique (attached behavior) is probably the only possible option in the style of MVVM, if not including `Interaction.Triggers`.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up solving this using an attached behaviour. It's a little cumbersome, but it does work. Basically, you can put an `ICommand` on your ViewModel, whose `Execute` method is called with `true` as the parameter as the mouse enters, and `false` as it leaves, allowing you to respond to hover over in the view model.

```
public static class MouseOverHelpers
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverCommand =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseOverCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseOverHelpers),
                                                                new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var ui = dependencyObject as UIElement;
        if (ui == null) return;

        if (args.OldValue != null)
        {
            ui.RemoveHandler(UIElement.MouseLeaveEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MouseLeave));
            ui.RemoveHandler(UIElement.MouseEnterEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MouseEnter));
        }

        if (args.NewValue != null)
        {
            ui.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeaveEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MouseLeave));
            ui.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseEnterEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MouseEnter));
        }
    }

    private static void ExecuteCommand(object sender, bool parameter)
    {
        var dp = sender as DependencyObject;
        if (dp == null) return;

        var command = dp.GetValue(MouseOverCommand) as ICommand;
        if (command == null) return;

        if (command.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            command.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }

    private static void MouseEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteCommand(sender, true);
    }

    private static void MouseLeave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteCommand(sender, false);
    }

    public static void SetMouseOverCommand(DependencyObject o, ICommand value)
    {
        o.SetValue(MouseOverCommand, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetMouseOverCommand(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(MouseOverCommand) as ICommand;
    }
}
```

And it's used like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Border Name="Border"
           my:MouseOverHelpers.MouseOverCommand="{Binding MouseOverCommand}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="32" Height="32" Margin="2,0,2,0"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Do not know how others, but I like this solution.